# Usercontrol style trigger not working

Tags: wpf, user-controls, triggers

I am pretty sure this question has been asked from time to time since I found another question with about the same contents, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796297/wpf-usercontrols-triggers-and-changing-other-controls). But when I try to figure using all those pages, I'm just stuck...
This is what I'm trying to do. I created a usercontrol to select a file and show the path to the file in a textbox. Just like in HTML (input type=file). That all works great and as expected. But when I try to change the colour of the textbox using a trigger (FilePathIsValid), it just does not work. The dependency properties all work fine, as said above. But the style just is not assigned to the textbox.
Here is my XAML - can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? (Code Behind [here](http://pastebin.com/GjW1MtNS), if needed)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Controls.SelectFileBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Project.Controls"
         x:Name="ThisUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- This does not work... -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:SelectFileBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="FilePathIsValid" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="TextBoxBorderColor" Value="red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <!-- Neither does this: FilePathIsValid can't be found -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="FilePathIsValid" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl,Path=TextBoxIsEnabled}" Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl,Path=FilePath}" BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=TextBoxBorderThickness}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,3,3,3" Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=ButtonText}" Click="SelectFileClick"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You have style for `SelectFileBox` and have no elements of that type in the `UserControl`.

Comment: Yea, I thought so as well.. Thing is,  I can't use 'UserControl' in stead of 'SelectFileBox', because then the properties are not recognised.. Is there a 'workaround' (not in code)?

Comment: Since you dont have any elements of type `SelectFileBox`, your style will not be applied to any element. You might want to try changing your textbox to SelectFileBox.

Comment: Please check the first line of my XAML; this UserControl is the 'SelectFileBox'. That's probably also the cause of the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understood the problem after looking at the codebehind.

All you need to do is add a binding to the `BorderBrush` property on the TextBox like below to get the right `BorderBrush` applied.

```
BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=TextBoxBorderColor}"
```

Full XAML for TextBox element:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl,Path=TextBoxIsEnabled}"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl,Path=FilePath}" 
         BorderThickness="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=TextBoxBorderThickness}" 
         BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=TextBoxBorderColor}"/>
```

I have tried and tested, below is the screenshot

### [image: Sample Output]

**Alternative Way:**

You could have a style for `TextBox` and have data triggers to change the borderbrush:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
       <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, 
                         Path=FilePathIsValid}" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

With this approach, you don't need style for `SelectFileBox` and binding for `BorderBrush` property on `TextBox`.

Comment: Ok... But then, is there another way to change the border colour when `FilePathIsValid` is false?

Comment: Updated answer with an alternative approach to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Datatrigger, hea? I would not have guessed that (since I never used it before). Thanks man, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to set the textBoxbroder as red if the path is invalid then change your code as below

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="FilePathIsValid" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried that (and just now again) but then the thing is 'FilePathIsValid' is not recognised...

Comment: As far as i understood the code what ever your referring is custom control. If you are trying to use that directly then it'll not work for you. You should take that control and use it. It has only the C# part but it dosent contain the code for XMal, so are you trying to write the XMAL part?

Comment: What you're saying is that I can only do that when I'm using the control? I can't write the trigger in the control (XAML) itself? (That would kinda suck since its the same everywhere.) I can write it in the code behind, but I don't prefer that..